Epic kayak stability
If you try to remount on the epic kayaks they are very stable and do not tend to flip easly
They have very big aspect ratio, shallow waterline and not deep keel - they look like they should rotate easly (though they are very stable)
So how do they achive such stability ?

Which models? They make a few.  And what are you comparing them to.  But they look wide, and that helps

V8 but as far as dimentions they are mostly the same the difference mainly is in the length

They make touring kayaks as well, which will handle differently to surfskis

This question could be improved with a link or an image

Welcome to GIS SE.
Please take a look at the [Tour].
And please also [edit] some extra info into the body of the question for clarification -- rather than only in the comments.
